# Unity Shader: Scrolling Textures, then add Alpha Mask

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

It may seem pretty basic for someone familiar with shaders, but I have two shaders at the moment, the first one just scrolls a texture two times, and its working as it should so far.

The second shader is the one that's just using another Texture as an alpha mask.

How do I combine those two shaders, so that the result of the two scrolling mainTex from the first shader will get alpha masked the same way as the second shader ?

First shader with 2 scrolling mainTex

```
Shader "Custom/TwoScrolling" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Rays texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _speed ("Speed", Float) = 0.2
}

Category {
    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    Blend SrcAlpha One

    Cull Off Lighting Off ZWrite Off Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) }

    BindChannels {
        Bind "Color", color
        Bind "Vertex", vertex
        Bind "TexCoord", texcoord
    }

    SubShader {
        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _speed;

            float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR {

                i.uv.x += cos(_Time*_speed);

                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert_img
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _MainTex;
            float _speed;

            float4 frag(v2f_img i) : COLOR {

                i.uv.x += sin(_Time*_speed);

                return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

}

Second shader with seperate alpha mask

```
Shader "Separate Alpha Mask" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Alpha ("Alpha (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType" = "Transparent" "Queue" = "Transparent"}

    ZWrite Off

    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    ColorMask RGB

    Pass {
        SetTexture[_MainTex] {
            Combine texture
        }
        SetTexture[_Alpha] {
            Combine previous, texture
        }
    }
}
```

}